# Add @Target Api(MARSHMALLOW) Annotation

Tags: java, android

I go following issues when I develop android app
Add `@Target Api(MARSHMALLOW)` Annotation.
How can I fix it?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using. Its for API 23

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object getSystemService(String)` instead of the `T getSystemService(Class<T>)` overload that is only available from API level 23 onwards.